# How to get value by giving the name from a resx file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which is localized for the language English, my default language for the application is Dutch.

What I want is the following:
I want to get the value by giving the name (of a label) from a specific resx file (the Dutch version beneath my form)

Name                             Value 
[image: The resx file]

This because I want to get the lenght of the default language label text.

Comment: If you are planning to store string values, use the Settings.settings file

Comment: The values of the labels are stored default in "form1.resx"

Comment: Could you please explain what have you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can't get to the resx file beneath my form1

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx link will explain you how to localize application.

Comment: Localizing a form is very simple, you set the Localizable property to True and change the Language property to enter strings.  The designer automatically generates the .resx files for each language and generates the code to retrieve the localized value of the Text property at runtime.  Which makes finding the length of the string completely trivial as well, you simply pass label1.Text to TextRenderer.MeasureText().

Comment: I know, "I have a form which is localized for the language English" I need the default text length because I have another project which has 700 forms. these translated texts are overlapping my controls. I want to break the texts based on the default text. so that I dont have to reposition everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using this to translate my app to french...use ResourceManager

```
ResourceManager rm = Resources.fr.ResourceManager;
rm.GetString("your_var_name")
```

else use

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager (typeof(your_form_class))
rm.GetString("your_var_name")
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Yes, but I can't get to the form1>form1.resx

Comment: How are you accessing your resx file then ?

Comment: I can open it but I don't know how I have to access it through the code

Comment: Have you tried my way ("fr" is the name of my resx file)? It loads the  string directly from the resx file

Comment: Can you please edit your post and give us some code so we can see what you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48958/discussion-between-yan-veilleux-and-castrovalva)